# How to send data in js to server on refresh or close?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a webpage which is basically a countdown timer. The initial value of the timer is received from server. What I want to do is to save the remaining value of the timer when the page is closed or refreshed. Are there any way to do this without syncing the value of the timer periodically?

Comment: Anything is possible but there seems to be some missing information here, are you using straight JS or is jQuery in the mix? Where do you want to store the value? e.g. mySQL, mongoDB, etc. Do you have existing code to show us or do you expect us to write it for you?

Comment: If it's a countdown timer, you should be using a timestamp for the end time, which need not change.

Comment: event though the possible overload, syncing the timer periodically could be a good idea in case the browser is closed abruptly by killing its process

Comment: another thought, if you're just trying to cache a timer, why not store the value in a cookie every time the timer is updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `window.onbeforeunload`. It is called before the browser changes the page (either by closing or navigating away), and you could use it to send the data back, something like:

```
window.onbeforeunload = sendTimeToServer;
function sendTimeToServer() {
    // some ajax code
}
```

Comment: this is one of the few cases where you'd need to use a synchronous call for XHR.

Comment: That seems to be exactly what I am trying to do. I am going to do this right now.

Comment: @zzzzBov Good point, but only if you want a response. If you are happy to just fire off some kind of 'user 1234 counted down to 4567' message, you needn't hang around.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. And There aren't any failures sending ajax request so far, although shabunc said otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

In the aspx file of the page, add the following to the Body tab:

```
<body onUnload="someMethod()"/>
```

Then in this method:

```
<script language="JavaScript"> 
    function someMethod() 
    {   
        var value = ""; //You need to set the timer value here
        document.cookie = "timercookie" + "=" + escape(value) + "; path=/" + "; expires=Thu, 2 Aug 2001 20:47:11 UTC"; 
    } 
</script>
```

You need to store the value in a cookie and then retrieve it later when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, the short answer is - it is impossible.

The longer one is - we can send an ajax request (or iframe or whatever) but there is no guarantee it will not be aborted by the browser (actually, it likely will).

A little bit longer answer is - we can try to send a synchronous XMLHttpRequest on onbeforeunload event (somebody called such requests synced ajax - which is funny, because first a stands for "asynchronous") - but synched ajax call are headache. If you you have an option not to use them - you'd better not.

I can recommend you to store specific data in localStorage and to try to send to the server it next time user will visit the page.